# Jeff Sharkey Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter, simpleadapter

I'm relatively new to Android and Java so forgive me if this is a stupid question. I'm using Jeff Sharkeys SeperatedListAdapter and I'd like to create a list like below, where it goes **HEAD** item_complex.xml, list_item.xml, item_complex.xml ANOTHER **HEADER** ...and so on but I'm failing to comprehend what needs to be done to achieve this. most likely due to my lack of android and java knowledge. Could someone help me out please?

[image: Example]

if it helps...code...

```
package com.biosonik.iceland.news;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import com.biosonik.iceland_planner.R;

public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

    public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();  
    public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;  
    public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;  

    public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {  
        headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);  
    }  

    public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {  

             this.headers.add(section);

        this.sections.put(section, adapter);  
    }  

    public Object getItem(int position) {  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return section;  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    public int getCount() {  
        // total together all sections, plus one for each section header  
        int total = 0;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getCount() + 1;  
        return total;  
    }  

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {  
        // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections  
        int total = 1;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        return total;  
    }  

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {  
        int type = 1;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;  
            if(position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }  

    public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {  
        return false;  
    }  

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {  
        return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);  
    }  

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        int sectionnum = 0;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            sectionnum++;  


        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        return position;  
    }  

}
```

Activity...

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.planner_list);



        List<Map<String,?>> security = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
    week34.add(createItem("62","Monday 19th Novermber","C1P1 Change-Over Day 1", "text text text text",String.valueOf(R.drawable.lsnow),"9C"));  
    week35.add(createItem("52","Monday 19th Novermber", "C1P1 Change-Over Day 2", "text text text text",String.valueOf(R.drawable.hsnow),"12C"));  



    // create our list and custom adapter  
    SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);  


    adapter.addSection("Week 34", 
            new SimpleAdapter(DisplayNewsActivity.this, week34, R.layout.list_complex,  
                    new String[] {ITEM_UID, ITEM_DATE, ITEM_HEADLINE, ITEM_GRAB_LINE, ITEM_WEATHER_TEMP, ITEM_WEATHER_ICON }, new int[] {R.id.uid, R.id.date, R.id.headline, R.id.grab_line,R.id.weather_icon,R.id.weather_temp }));  
    adapter.addSection("UNWANTED HEADER", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "SIMPLE LIST ENTRY" })); 

    adapter.addSection("Week 35", 
            new SimpleAdapter(DisplayNewsActivity.this, week35, R.layout.list_complex,  
                    new String[] {ITEM_UID, ITEM_DATE, ITEM_HEADLINE, ITEM_GRAB_LINE, ITEM_WEATHER_TEMP, ITEM_WEATHER_ICON }, new int[] {R.id.uid, R.id.date, R.id.headline, R.id.grab_line,R.id.weather_icon,R.id.weather_temp }));  


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); 
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: feel a bit silly. Logic would say I just called adapter.sections.put("section",adapter); instead of addsection()...I haven't testing this brain fart but i'm sure its right...

Answer (score 0):

In `getViewTypeCount()`, why does it assume that headers count as one? In the way I see this method, there would be **two diferente kind of view for each section**, so for example, with 2 sections you would have 4 types of view instead of 3 as it is being brought by this code (Apologies for my english)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18343056)

Comment: I'm trying to help him by him helping me understand his code, why do I need reputation for that sir?

Comment: For there are two diferente types of views for each section and it seems like he is passing through all of the sections in there. So why only adding one for the first header and not for the others?